# Android: How to create popup with choices

Tags: android

I want to do something like this: user clicks on a button "Choose color", and a simple popup with e.g. 5 colors appears. I could do this with PopupWindow and inner ListView, but is there a simpler solution, like a specific widget for this?

How it should look like: [image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `AlertDialog.Builder` and supply an `Adapter` via `setAdapter()` that generates your rows.